# C - Block others from writing to a file

Tags: c, permissions, fifo

I have multiple process writing to a FIFO file. While one of them is writing, I want to prevent other processes from writing to the file.

I am using read and write calls to access the FIFO file.

Example: There are two C-programs Server.c and Client.c. Multiple clients are writing to the FIFO file created by the server program. Server should be able to read and write from the file at any time where as only one client can access the file at a time.

Comment: You can consider inter-process synchronization methods,mutex ,semaphores, etc.

Comment: I am sorry, The question I asked was not clear enough, I have edited the it, Clients writing to the file are independent of each other. Can I use semaphores for them

Answer (score 0):

Try by using locking mechanisms..try concurrent read and exclusive  write mechanisms (CREW)  implementations.

```
 void ReaderThread::run()
    {
        ...
        semaphore++;
        read_file();
        semaphore--;
        ...
    }

    void WriterThread::run()
    {
        ...
        semaphore += MaxReaders;
        write_file();
        semaphore -= MaxReaders;
        ...
    }
```

With this solution, up to MaxReaders threads can read from the file at the same time. As soon as a writer thread wants to modify the file, it tries to allocate all the semaphore's resources, thus making sure that no other thread can access the file during the write operation.

Comment: I if, do not use O_UNBLOCK when calling the open function for writing will it block the file until some process reads from it?

Comment: I am sorry, The question I asked was not clear enough, I have edited the it, How do I use semaphores, mutex for that specific problem

Comment: Take care with your policy of server can access at any time. You need to writelock when a client is writing and read lock on the server side this will ensure that only complete data is on the queue.